# installing Lubunto/linux on laptop wireless not working-- broadcom 802.11n?

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, uefi, laptop, broadcom

I am using an acer v5-471 laptop with 8gb ram, windows is laggy and I want to switch to linux, I took a particular interest in kali and downloaded it on a usb and booted it, it worked fine but the wireless didnt work, not sure why, with broadcom 802.11n network card.

Discovered lubuntu yesterday and want to try getting it, but I also want the same capabilities as kali linux, like penetration testing and those programs that come with kali.

I am wondering if you can help me with how and if I should install lubuntu, and fix the problem with my kali (I ordered a usb ethernet connection) such that I use lubunto and and boot kali whenever I want because lubunto is lightweight or if it is better to fix kali and just use that.

Anyways I want to remove my windows 8 uefi 64-bit crap, and replace it with linux, be lightweight and still have kali linux programs and capabilities, and deal with the no wireless issue which I tried to deal with for hours.

Also wondering if and how this would affect my touch screen on my laptop, I've looked everywhere and can't find answers I hope anyone hear can help me.

Comment: you need to display the information from `lspci -v` that corresponds to your wireless adapter from broadcom to receive help.

Comment: Ubuntu has touch screen support (not sure about lubuntu though). You can use git to clone the kali repos from http://git.kali.org/gitweb/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your device is BCM43227 "14e4:4358"

Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-*
sudo modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
sudo modprobe wl
echo 'wl' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

See here: [help.ubuntu.com/community/BroadcomSTA(Wireless)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BroadcomSTA%28Wireless%29#broadcom-sta-source_.2B-_broadcom-sta-common_works_for_model_numbers)

[More info from Debian here about building the DKMS module](https://wiki.debian.org/wl)